# How can I see whether my sprite is .png or .jpg in the Inspector view or some place alike in Unity?

Tags: unity, editors, ide, extension

How can I see whether my sprite is `.png` or `.jpg` in the Inspector view or some place alike in Unity?

Here is an example of me trying to get the file extension using Editor:

[image]

Comment: Why would you need this anyways?

Comment: @Charanor, the reason I asked it because if it is possible to get the extension through only Editor that means I do not know the way to do it. So, if the way exists I hope to find a new, maybe very small and not that significant, Unity Editor capability which will enable me to some stuff I was not enabled before. In a shell, being able to get such info using only Editor extends my knowledge about Editor, so it is mostly just about proficiency while exploiting the Editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it right your question just show the extensions of sprite in Unity Editor?

That's simple.

You just change to 2 Column Layout of Project window.

[image: change to layout]

Comment: Lol. I knew that way! Thanks a lot for reminding about it. I will wait a little bit maybe someone will give another way of doing it, the way which I did not know. And then I will accept your answer.

Comment: @Yaroslav I think that's the only way. I had a thought about another one, but I checked it and nope, it doesn't say.  However you can right click an asset and say "show in explorer" which would pop up a standard file browser centered on the asset. But that's not "within Unity."